# cakephp: image not displaying

Tags: image, cakephp

i'm trying to get an image to display in the cupcake forum and it is not displaying. Only the alt is showing up. Can someone tell me on what i'm doing wrong? My code:

```
  <?php echo $html->image('/forum/vendors/img/goto.png', array('alt' => 'goto', 'url' => array('controller' => 'topics', 'action' => 'view', $category['lastTopic_id'], 'page' => $category['LastTopic']['page_count'], '#' => 'post_'. $category['lastPost_id']))); ?>
```

thank you.

Comment: Where is the image supposed to be?

Comment: in c:/websites/merry_flowers/plugins/forum/vendors/img/

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp's image URLs are relative to /app/webroot/img/, so assuming your app is named merry_flowers, you should have:

```
<?php echo $html->image('../../plugins/forum/vendors/img/goto.png', /*Rest goes here */; ?>
```

Or something similar, depending on your directory structure.

Comment: i tried swiecki's first suggestion: '../../plugins/forum/vendors/img/goto.png' and it is not working.

Comment: Do a mental exercise: start in the webroot/img/ directory, then for every directory level up you have to go, add a ../ to the path. Once you are at your app level, add the folders that you navigate through to get to your image.

Comment: I had just put the directory level according to what i see in windows explorer which is what I told you earlier ../../plugins/forum/vendors/img/goto/png'. Ok, i guess i just have to keep trying. :)